# How to access model array in a Jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have the following line in my HTML code :

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.BgtArray" id="BudgetArray"/>
```

Here, BgtArray is a 2-D array which gets populated in the view itself. Something like this:

```
@for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{@for (j=0;j<10;j++)
   @Model.BgtArray[i][j]= *some value*;
}
```

How do i access this array's elements in a jQuery function??

Answer (score 3):

You are populating the model inside the view???? In the MVC pattern views are intended to display data that is passed to them under the form of a model. It is the controller's responsibility to populate this model.

This being said let's suppose that you have a model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int[][] BgtArray { get; set; }
}
```

which is populated inside the controller action and passed to the view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            BgtArray = Enumerable
                .Range(1, 10)
                .Select(
                    i => Enumerable
                            .Range(1, 10)
                            .Select(j => i * j)
                            .ToArray()
                )
                .ToArray()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and then we could have a corresponding strongly typed view in which we could JSON serialize the model and access it in javascript:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    alert(model.BgtArray[1][2]);
</script>
```

which will be rendered in the browser like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = {"BgtArray":[[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[3,6,9]]};
    alert(model.BgtArray[1][2]);
</script>
```

As far as the following line is concerned:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.BgtArray" id="BudgetArray"/>
```

it's pretty useless because you cannot store entire complex object graphs into a hidden field. The rendered result will be:

```
<input type="hidden" value="System.Int32[][]" id="BudgetArray"/>
```

which is very unlikely to be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey Darin. Thanks a ton for you response. however, im getting the following error on running your code: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. its occuring in this line: var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

Comment: That's because you have circular references. You cannot JSON serialize object graphs with circular references. I would recommend you to use a view model instead of passing your domain models to the views and break this circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem with circular references (mentioned in the comments below the answer for the original question), I used this instead of `Json.Encode`:

```
@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```

In your classes, use the following annotation to make Json ignore the navigation properties that cause trouble:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
```

Solution taken from: [Hide field in model when using @Json.Encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263436/hide-field-in-model-when-using-json-encode)